# JavaScript keyup event bug

Tags: javascript

I have annoying bug in my code. On event key Enter, the user is not able to add item unless the first item is added manually(on click Add). How can I fix this? I appreciate any help or hints how to solve it! Thank you!

```js
function selectColorStatus(event){
    let target = event.target;
    target.classList.toggle('todoTextSelected');
}



function createToDoItem(userInputValue){
    // To-Do Item Container
    let todoItem = document.createElement("div");
    todoItem.classList.add("row", "flx");
    todoItem.onclick = selectColorStatus;

    // Inner Text
    let todoText = document.createElement('div');
    todoText.classList.add('grow');
    todoText.innerText = userInputValue;


    // Date 
    let CreateDate = document.createElement('div');
    CreateDate.classList.add('date');
    let date = new Date();
    year = date.getFullYear();
    month = date.getMonth();
    day = date.getDay();
    CreateDate.innerText = 'Created at ' + year + '-' +  month  + '-'+ day;

    // Delete Button
    let deleteBtn = document.createElement('div');
    deleteBtn.classList.add('btnDelete');
    deleteBtn.innerText = 'X';
    deleteBtn.onclick = function(){
        todoItem.remove();
    }
    
    
    todoItem.appendChild(todoText);
    todoItem.appendChild(CreateDate)
    todoItem.appendChild(deleteBtn);

    let todoItemsContainer = document.getElementById('todoItemsContainer');
    todoItemsContainer.appendChild(todoItem);
}

// Item Entry and Validation
function ToDoItemHandler(){
    let userInput = document.getElementById('toDoEntry');
    let userInputValue = userInput.value;
    

    if(userInputValue == ''){
        alert('Entry can not be empty!')
    }else{
        userInput.onkeydown = pressFunc;
        function pressFunc(e){
            if(e.key == 'Enter' || e.key == 13){
                createToDoItem(userInputValue);
                userInput.value = '';
            }
        }
        createToDoItem(userInputValue);
        userInput.value = '';
    }


}
// Clear List
let btnDeleteItem = document.getElementById('btnDeleteItem');
btnDeleteItem.onclick = function (){
    // or document.getElementById('todoItemsContainer').innerHTML = ''
    const items = document.querySelectorAll('.row')
    items.forEach(el => {
    el.remove()
    })
}


// Add Item Button
let btnAddItem = document.getElementById('btnAddItem');
btnAddItem.onclick = ToDoItemHandler;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href = './style/style.css' rel='stylesheet'>
    <title>To-Do-List</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id = 'container'>
        <div id="toDoHeader">
            <h1>To-Do List</h1>
            <div id = 'toDoContent'>
                <input type = 'text' id = 'toDoEntry' name = 'toDoEntry' placeholder = 'Add item here'>
                <button type = 'button' id = 'btnAddItem' name = 'addToDoList'>Add</button>
                <button type = 'button' id = 'btnDeleteItem' name = 'deleteList'>Delete All</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="todoItemsContainer">
        </div>
    </div>


    
    <script src = './js/app.js'></script>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is because you set the event listener (for the enter key press) on the input only when you click for the first time the "Add Item" button. You should setup it when body is ready :)

Comment: Please avoid this nonsense with the duplicated text. Extending the explanation of your question might be a good idea, though.

Answer (score 1):

Your event handler for onKeyDown will be created after you click btnAddItem.

you have to put this " userInput.onkeydown = pressFunc; " outside the function. so the event handler registered without click the btnAddItem first. do it like you register btnAddItem event handler below // Add Item Button